# SSH key added on boot without password prompt - how and why?

Tags: reboot, ssh-agent, kexec

I have a passphrase-protected SSH key stored in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. In my `.zshrc` I have this fragment:

```
if ! ssh-add -l > /dev/null; then
  ssh-add
fi
```

After booting, I usually open the terminal, see the passphrase prompt, then unlock my KeePass 2 DB, copy the passphrase to clipboard and paste it into the terminal to add the key to the agent.

A few days ago, I have rebooted the system, logged in, and opened the terminal. To my surprise, the passphrase prompt didn't appear. Surprised, I typed `ssh-add -l` to see my key already added. That was weird, but I hand-waved it away, thinking that I forgot that I've already typed the password.

A moment ago, I ran `sudo systemctl kexec`, and after logging in, the key was already added again. My KeePass DB was locked. The passphrase is long and random (`/[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}/`). This time I suspected it's something specific to `kexec`, but after yet another `sudo systemctl kexec`, the passphrase prompt appeared, the key wasn't added to the agent.

- How come my SSH key is sometimes added to the agent after reboot?
- <s>Can it also happen after a cold boot?</s> (yes)
- What can I do to prevent it?

I'm using Pop!_OS 18.04, booting with UEFI off a GPT disk with LUKS-encrypted `/` and unencrypted `/boot,` no LVM if that matters.

---

*Edit:* I've just cold booted after 4 days and the key was already added to agent again.

Comment: Is your SSH key added to seahorse or some other key manager? It might add the keys automatically on login.

Comment: @muru No, not to my knowledge. I've removed Seahorse and didn't install anything in its place. And even if I did, I'd expect it to prompt for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Seahorse revealed that the key password was remembered in the system keyring. What was adding the key, I don't know, but I was able to remove the remembered password using Seahorse.